# Can't access a parent's variable from a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, requirejs

I have two functions.  I call one from the other and then try to access a variable in the scope of both function's parent.  This works fine as seen in the following javascript code:

```
var value = "A";

function func1() {
  console.log(this.value);
  func2();
}

function func2() {
  console.log(value);
}
```

**Question 1:**
Why is value undefined in func2 when wrapping in require.js like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/70xfVWKFnZBQKS1y0I7G)?

**Question 2:**
Why do I have to use this.value in func1?

Comment: You tagged this [tag:requirejs] but in order to see how RequireJS figures in your problem you send readers off-site. All the information which is essential to understanding the issue should be *in the body of your question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/K7TSOypqKyBQEOqseGqP?p=preview to see that var value is accessed from func2.

I found a solution for you: add setValue to problem.js:

```
function setValue(val) {
  value = val;
}
```

and make it public:

```
return {func1: func1, setValue:setValue};
```

and from initialize.js call it:

```
problem.setValue("D");
```

Now from each function in problem (func1, func2) you can use `variable`. See it in my updated link.

It depends on the scope of the line `var value`. Usually when you put this js in a html, then the scope is window, as well as this inside func1.

func 2 should work as well, as scope is window as well, it just doesn't work in the linked example, because there it's not loaded into the window directly.

Comment: Thank you, Gavriel.  My understanding with require.js, is that each module (file) has local variables that are accessible to other modules only by including a dependancy to that module (define(["problem.js"], function (problem) ...) and then accessing them through the parameter passed in (problem).  I want to keep variables private to each module, except through these dependancies.  Is it impossible to call functions in this way without globals?

Comment: In the 1st "non working" example you can see func2 is working and it does use the module-local value. I think that in your example it works the opposite way. In func1 this.value is the module-local. You should use this.value also in func2.

Comment: value should have been initialized by initialize.js, line 4 before func1 was called, so shouldn't value = A already?  This is the value I want persisted.  Are we looking at two different instances of problem.js?

Comment: I only edited problem.js. initilize.js sets problem.value = "A". I only added value = "B" in global scope to show it's not overriding it. It prints A and C, but not B

Comment: So, the problem is that initialize doesn't change problem's value.  How can this be done from initialize.js?

Comment: But it does! func1 prints A, which is set from initialize. That's the way you access it from the module: this.value, not value.

Comment: OK, this has me quite confused.  As I understand it now, we can only access value from func2 if it is set within problem (your line, var value = "C"), not from a different module.

Comment: Thanks!  That last plunk gave a lot of insight into what is actually going on.  I guess I'll use a setter for value, as you suggest.  Looks like I'll be reading more about the keyword this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may be confusing the two values.

`this.value` get's the property `value` of `this`, where `this` is being set by the function. `func1()`

Now, your `var value;` is undefined because you never set a value to it.

- `this.value` is a property of `this`
- `console.log(value)` is trying to print the value of `var value;` which is undefined, because you never actually set it to anything

Comment: Thank you, I saw I forgot to initialize value and fixed it.  Did you look at my linked example?

Comment: @Nate I glanced at it, but I do not see it now. Are you still having issues?

Comment: Yes.  In my linked example, I can't seem to set value on the module named problem from another module (initialize) and access the value set in func2.